# qed symbol not correctly aligned when ending a proof with a diagram

Tags: amsmath, theorems, amsthm

I know there is a myriad of questions about the alignment of the tombstone symbol, but I couldn't see any one that addresses this little issue.

Say you end your proof with a diagram such as the following:

`\[\xymatrix{A & B \\ C & D} \]`

Then the little tombstone symbol will be way one line further down from where it should be. If I add `\qedhere` just after the diagram, then the tombstone is aligned with the B in the diagram, which is just wrong.

How do I get it right?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} A theorem.
\begin{proof}
\[\xymatrix{A & B \\ C & D} \]
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} A theorem.
\begin{proof}
\[\xymatrix{A & B \\ C & D} \qedhere \]
\end{proof}
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the issue?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three possible styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\[
\xymatrix{A & B \\ C & D} \qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
\[
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix{A & B \\ C & D}\\
\end{gathered}
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
\[
\begin{gathered}[b]
\xymatrix{A & B \\ C & D}\\[-\dp\strutbox]
\end{gathered}
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the last one, the adjustment may depend on what's in the bottom row of the diagram.

Comment: Magic. I've no idea how it works but the last one does just what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoStonek I use `\begin{gathered}[b]` that sets the reference point at the bottom row of itself; however, I have to use a fake second row, which is empty, which `\qedhere` uses for the reference point; but some adjustment has to be made, because each cell in the `\xymatrix` has a `\strut` in it, so I backup by its depth.

Comment: @egreg: Makes me wonder why amongst the myriad of theorem packages, no-one seems to have tried a zero-height line with a smashed tombstone at the end, but that would probably put the tombstone even further down than your third variant.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz “There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy”: what about a last line almost full, with the smashed tombstone overlapping with text? `;-)`